# how to place fetched data in their respective input fields (input fields are created dynamically)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, content-management-system

***Providing some background story:***

I am working on a edit button for my Content Management System, but I am bumping into a couple of problems now. I am finishing someone else his part (he built the CMS and I got assigned to his project and had to finish what he started basically) so there are certain parts I cannot edit or change.

***Problem:***

You can dynamically create input fields in the C.M.S, and then insert the data into Mysqli. Right now I am fetching the data successfully, but stumble upon the following problem: The input fields were created like this:

```
<input type="text" name="example[]" id="example[]"> //note the square brackets
```

and I cannot assign an incremented counter on these IDs, so I can assign my fetched data to the input fields. 
I am trying to loop through all of my data sets and then insert the first data it fetches to the first input field and the second data to the second input field and so on.

I was able to dynamically create the same amount of input fields, but the main problem is adding all the data to an individual input field. I keep on getting the last fetched data in all of my input fields.

***What I have tried and how I tried inserting data1 in input field 1 and so on:***

I know this sucks and I know it doesn't work and why it doesn't work, but I'll throw it in for you to get an idea.

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
        $("#example\\[" + "\\]").each(function() { //already tried incrementing this part by using i as a counter, but it doesn't recognize the id when I use i as a counter.
            $("#example\\[" + "\\]").val(response[i].exampleType);
        });
}
```

***What I am trying to achieve:***

- I am trying to loop through my database rows (success)
- Fetch it via JSON (success)
- Dynamically create the input fields based on the amount of fetched data (success)
- Insert data1 from database in the first input field and data2 in the second input field and so on (this is where it goes wrong, I cannot, or don't know how, to increment an input field with the square brackets to insert my fetched data in the input fields).

***Example:***

You have fetched your data in JSON format via ajax, your response parameter looks like this:

```
response = JSON.parse(response);
```

You have 2 rows in your database: row1 (from JSON.parse[0]) and row1 (from JSON.parse[1])

You have created the 2 input fields, dynamically (because you have response[0].example and response[1].example), but both input fields look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="example[]" id="example[]">
```

So that means you have dynamically created the following:

```
<input type="text" name="example[]" id="example[]">
<input type="text" name="example[]" id="example[]">
```

Now you have to insert row1 (from response[0].example) in the first input field and the other row1 (from response[1].example) into the second one.

How could such thing be achieved?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to fill your inputs with your data fetched from your database ?

Comment: Yes, that is very much correct! But all the inputs, as you can see, have the bracket notation (to insert into the database that way), and I don't know how to fetch all my data now, and fill my input fields with it.

Comment: When you're looping over your json response, can't you simply set value attribute of each input with current response element ?

Comment: But that's the problem, how do I target each input individual? Since they all have the same name and id etc. I can't, or don't know how, to give it an ID incrementation either or else my compiler can't target that certain ID, since it has an incremented counter

Comment: You parse your json with Javascript, so use it at the same time to generate your inputs : so either you create inputs like shown in your post (with brackets so data are sent in arrays) or custom ones that fit your needs ?

Comment: Could you submit an example? I kind of understand what you mean though.

Answer (score 0):

```
your_json_array.forEach( function(obj) { //loop over your json array

    var input = document.createElement("input"); //create an input

    input.setAttribute("name", "yourname"); //custom it
    input.setAttribute("value", obj.value); //custom it
    //etc...

    your_div.appendChild(input); //appends it where you want
});
```

Obj is an element of your response and value one of it property